# Flattening nested events/documents in Logstash

Tags: xml, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash to parse a nested multiline XML document and forward it to Elasticsearch.

Such a document might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root_Element xmlns:ns2="some_namespace">
    <creationTime>2016-02-05T00:27:29.752Z</creationTime>
    <provider>some_provider</provider>
    <Event>
        <eventId>111999_0</eventId>
        <something_interesting some_attribute="foo" other_attribute="bar" yet_another_attribute="whatever"/>
        <eventStartTime>2016-01-22T04:00:00Z</eventStartTime>
        <eventStopTime>2016-02-19T18:00:00Z</eventStopTime>
        <location loc_attribute="fooz" other_loc_attribute="unknown" and_one_more="hooray">
            <xy lat="51.514728" lon="-0.073563" name="some_name" direction="north"/>
        </location>
        <comment language="en">Some text comment.</comment>
        <comment language="en">Some other text comment.</comment>
    </Event>
</Root_Element>
```

To read this document in Logstash, I use the following config file:

```
##########
# INPUT
##########

input {

    # listen on tcp
    tcp {
        port => 9000

        # do not split events on newlines but read multiple lines at once instead
        # events start with <Event>, everything that is not <Event> or </Root_Element> belongs to the previous event
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "(?=<Event>)(?=</Root_Element>)"
            negate => "true"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}

##########
# FILTER
##########

filter {

    # parse event input as Xml
    xml {
        source => "message"
        remove_namespaces => true
        store_xml => true
        target => "parsed"
    }

    # split event by Event tag
    split {
        field => "parsed[Event]"
    }

    # flatten the nested event structure on to the root level
    ruby {
        code => "

            event['parsed']['Event'].each do |key, value|
                event[key] = value[0]
            end

        "
    }

    # remove unnecessary fields from the output
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["message", "parsed", "host", "port", "tags"]
    }

}

##########
# OUTPUT
##########

output {

    # forward event to the elasticsearch host
    # elasticsearch {
        # hosts => ["elasticsearch"]
    # }

    # write event on stdout for debugging
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

In order to test this, just save the XML content from above into a file, start Logstash with the provided configuration and send the XML content to logstash via `cat filename.xml | nc <logstash_ip_or_hostname> 9000`.

This results in the following output in Logstash:

```
{
               "@timestamp" => "2016-05-03T11:51:39.777Z",
                 "@version" => "1",
                  "eventId" => "111999_0",
    "something_interesting" => {
               "some_attribute" => "foo",
              "other_attribute" => "bar",
        "yet_another_attribute" => "whatever"
    },
           "eventStartTime" => "2016-01-22T04:00:00Z",
            "eventStopTime" => "2016-02-19T18:00:00Z",
                 "location" => {
              "loc_attribute" => "fooz",
        "other_loc_attribute" => "unknown",
               "and_one_more" => "hooray",
                         "xy" => [
            [0] {
                      "lat" => "51.514728",
                      "lon" => "-0.073563",
                     "name" => "some_name",
                "direction" => "north"
            }
        ]
    },
                  "comment" => {
        "language" => "en",
         "content" => "Some text comment."
    }
}
```

That's not too bad, however, the event contains strings (e.g. `eventId`), objects (e.g. `something_interesting`) and arrays of objects (e.g. `location => xy`) value. I would rather like the final event to be flat instead of nested because dealing with nested data in Elasticsearch and Kibana has some issues.

Besides, the original XML content has two `<comment>` tags but the second one does not make it into the output for some reason.

What I would like the output to look would be something along the lines of:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => "2016-05-03T12:00:54.182Z",
    "@version" => "1",
    "eventId" => "111999_0",
    "something_interesting.some_attribute" => "foo",
    "something_interesting.other_attribute" => "bar",
    "something_interesting.yet_another_attribute" => "whatever",
    "eventStartTime" => "2016-01-22T04:00:00Z",
    "eventStopTime" => "2016-02-19T18:00:00Z",
    "location.loc_attribute" => "fooz",
    "location.other_loc_attribute" => "unknown",
    "location.and_one_more" => "hooray",
    "xy.0.lat" => "51.514728",
    "xy.0.lon" => "-0.073563",
    "xy.0.name" => "some_name",
    "xy.0.direction" => "north",
    "comment.0.language" => "en",
    "comment.0.content" => "Some text comment.",
    "comment.1.language" => "en",
    "comment.1.content" => "Some other text comment.",
}
```

The separator token in the keys must not necessarily be a dot but could be anything else (I am not sure right now whether the dot is even allowed).

Any suggestions how this could be achieved? Would I have to write a custom Ruby plugin for this transformation to happen or can this be done with the built-in ones as well?

Comment: any news on this one?

Comment: Not from my side, unfortunately. Of course, you can always use any programming language of choice, do the flattening yourself there, then pass the data on to Logstash or write it to Elasticsearch directly.

Comment: the only solutions I saw in Logstash was to use ruby, and i dont really want to learn that:  filter {ruby{ }

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/flatten-json-array-in-logstash/399/3

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rmoff/6cb9e28245cde010e6f694348286046c